# Can't run SQL query via AJAX request, same type of AJAX query used and works fine everywhere other than this

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using this AJAX call everywhere else and it works like a charm but only this gives problem. I don't understand what is the problem? Why I'm getting "Error retried record:" still I don't see any problem and so easy.

PS: I echoed the values at AJAX side response and getting all three values there but database gives problem. More, same SQL query works fine at database side but when it deals with AJAX and PHP, it gives problem.

Values passed fine:

> id1=get-version&id2=machine055&id3=vmlab

Database query seems fine:

```
SELECT `version` FROM `table1` where `machine` = 'machine055'
```

PHP+UI:

```
serverChange.on('change', function(){
            $("#progress").show();
            var selectedServer = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/web/scripts.php",
                data: { id1: "get-version", id2: selectedServer, id3: "vmlab" },
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#progress").hide();
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });

        });
```

PHP+Ajax:

```
if ($_POST['id1'] == "get-version" && $_POST['id3'] == "vmlab") {

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd", "db");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `table1` where `machine` = '" .trim($_POST['id2']). "'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Machine retrieved successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Error retried record: " . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: you're passing id3 as selenium, and it's expecting vmlab

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, i was editing the post and typo remained. In fact, it is vmlab and then also it didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried to run query directly on server? are you getting any results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different approach and its working fine so not exploring much, here is the solution:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd", "db");
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `table1` where `machine` = '" .trim($_POST['id2']). "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row['version'];
    }

    echo ($rows[0]);

    $conn->close();
```

Thanks all for reading the issue and resolution.